# Content-type not showing properly

Tags: php, html, json, http-headers

I am trying to get content type of a page which is set to json.

```
<?php 
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo $requestContentType = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
?>
```

but its returning the below result.

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']` contains the contents of the `Accept:` header that the client sent to the server. Calling `header()` has no effect on that variable.

Comment: `header()` is for setting the headers that are sent from the server to the client.

Comment: And if you want to send JSON, you should do `echo json_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']);`

Comment: is there any other way to find the page content-type.?

Comment: You are setting the page content type with header(). Why do you want to get your own value?

Comment: Are you trying to get the content type of the posted data? That will be in `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']`. All headers that come from the client are put into `$_SERVER['HTTP_xxx']`, where `xxx` is the header name converted to uppercase and `-` replaced with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this the wrong way. It is **your browser**, that sends the `Accept` header you see here. It list the mime-types it can use to render a webpage.

So, for you to get `application/json` in that header, you should be looking at the code for sending the request to the server. You can't do anything about the standard browser interaction, **but** you change the `Accept` headers, when using AJAX.

For standard [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, */*');
xhr.open("GET", 'http://the.internet.org/users');
xhr.send();
```

Using new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, */*');
fetch('http://the.internet.org/users', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
});
```